# Colors.xml is generating some incomplete gradle-related code which even after replacing with correct code doesn't seem to work

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I know this is a bug in the IDE but it doesn't work even after uninstalling/reinstalling the latest version of Android i.e. Android 3.4 or deleting the both the android folders in C:/User/Username

1) Deleted C:\Users\Username.AndroidStudio3.4 and C:\Users\Username.android but didn't work

2) Uninstalled and reinstalled the latest version of Android even though the previous was also the latest

**colors.xml**

```
<application>
<component name="UpdatesConfigurable">
    <enabledExternalComponentSources>
        <item value="Android SDK" />
    </enabledExternalComponentSources>
    <option name="externalUpdateChannels"
```

**Error:**
         1: Error: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.

Changed it to the following which is also not working

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
        <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
        <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
        <color name="your_color">#FFFFFF</color>
    </resources>
```

**Error:**
          26: Error: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.

Can someone suggest what should be done?

Comment: If you think it is androidstudio problem, compile your code using command line. 'gradlew assembleDebug'

Comment: RanjanKumar  It says 
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Comment: You are running it from Android Studio Terminal. Is your build machine MAC?

Comment: No, it is WIndows

Comment: @Far no it is not incorrect

Answer (score 1):

If you think it is androidstudio problem, compile your code using command line. 'gradlew assembleDebug' as given in attached screen shot from windows android studio terminal.

[image: screen shot from windows android studio terminal]

Comment: do you mind explaining how that solves the problem the op is facing?

Comment: njzk2, i want @Far to check if building from commandline 'gradlew assembleDebug' will not throw this error.

Comment: that's not entirely obvious from the image without explanatory caption

Comment: @njzk2, i updated image with proper description. Thanks for guidance.